# impdp error with two excluded tables

Tags: oracle, impdp

I am trying to import a dump with the following:

```
echo "exit" | sqlplus sys/pass as sysdba @ABC_STAGE_V2.sql 
impdp ABC_STAGE_V2/ABC_STAGE_V2 remap_schema=abc_def_live:abc_stage_v2 remap_tablespace=ABC_DEF_LIVE:ABC_STAGE_V2 table_exists_action=replace REUSE_DATAFILES=N EXCLUDE=TABLE:"IN('AUDITTRACKING','TABLE_STATISTICS')" nologfile=Y  dumpfile=abc_def.dmp directory=abc_v2
```

But it complains about:

```
LRM-00116: syntax error at ')' following 'TABLE_STATISTICS'
```

I have tried with a parfile with the following content:

```
    root@ts1:/opt/import# cat parfile.par
remap_schema=abc_def_live:abc_stage_v2 
remap_tablespace=ABC_DEF_LIVE:ABC_STAGE_V2 
table_exists_action=replace 
REUSE_DATAFILES=N 
EXCLUDE=TABLE:"IN('AUDITTRACKING','TABLE_STATISTICS')" 
nologfile=Y  
dumpfile=abc_def.dmp 
directory=abc_v2
```

And then I execute:

```
echo "exit" | sqlplus sys/pass as sysdba @ABC_STAGE_V2.sql 
    impdp ABC_STAGE_V2/ABC_STAGE_V2 PARFILE=filename.par
```

And the result is the same... it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a parfile? I've had instances where it just hated the CLI syntax but putting it in a parfile cleans it right up.

Comment: I have already tried, and it doesn't work either, it ignores the exclude parameter.

Comment: Update your post to include the contents of your parfile, please.

Comment: When you use the parfile argument it negates the need to dictate the parameters being passed. Can you `cat filename.par` and just upload its contents?

Comment: I thought impdp was the one who called the parfile... as impdp command has the PARFILE=parfile.par parameter...

Comment: Correct. If you tried running this command with a parfile your execution would have looked like `impdp parfile=filename.par` I need you to post the **contents** of that parfile.

Comment: I insist... I have already posted it! Please read again my post... In the second half you find the contents of the parfile and the command with the parfile parameter... Or you mean that the parfile must contain ALL of the parameters? Then I have tried it wrong...

Comment: The parfile must contain all of the parameters then the only parameter you pass into the `impdp` command is the parfile.

Comment: OK then. I will try it and post the result.

Comment: I updated the post with what you requested @mmmmmpie

Comment: When you run your expdp command passing only the parfile you receive the same error? Can you just execute that and pass in the parameters manually for testing?

Comment: I don't get the parenthesis error, it simply ignores the exclude... I can try to pass the parameters manually...

Comment: Get rid if the nolog and put the output to a log file and see what it says.